# Got 404 from http://169.254.170.2/$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild

On AWS ECS or AWS CodeBuild etc, when trying to retrieve as credentials using:
http://169.254.170.2/$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

suddenly since Feb 7, 2019 -  I got 404 not found !

```
curl -qL -o aws_credentials.json http://169.254.170.2/$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

The expected result should be a valid json of the AWS Credentials session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After short investigation:**

I found that `$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` **already starts by a slash**  '`/`'

```
[e.g AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=/v2/credentials/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx]
```

**Solution:** just remove the slash after the IP.*

```
e.g http://169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

**TL;DR;**

I run `curl` with `-v` on AWS CodeBuild:

```
> GET //v2/credentials/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx HTTP/1.1
> Host: 169.254.170.2
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

**Conclusion**: since *Feb 6 or 7 2019*, AWS add a strict check and **broke** the request with 404
for double slash `//`

Comment: Are you still seeing this in AWS CodeBuild? If so, which region?

Comment: @SubinMathew right, seem that AWS fix it, with 301 redirection: 
```
 Trying 169.254.170.2...
* Connected to 169.254.170.2 (169.254.170.2) port 80 (#1)
> GET //v2/credentials/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 169.254.170.2
> Accept: */*
```

Comment: I've opened a bug for this on the ECS agent side here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1839.